# How to get the HWND of a Tkinter window on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How to get the `HWND` of a Tkinter window in python3 on windows?

- I would like to get the native window handle of the Tkinter window if possible.
- I would need either the `HWND` or `HDC` of the window to perform custom drawing operations.

Is there a way to get the `HWND` of the `Canvas` or any other child components?

> There is a way to list all the windows created by the current process. I am also able to iterate through the child windows of any window listed previously. This would be the *ugly solution* for the problem.

Please post any alternative solutions if Tkinter does not expose the handle directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what you need is the TopLevel window method.

Check out this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731093951id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.frame-method)

> **frame()** [[#](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731093951id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.frame-method)]
> Returns a string containing a system-specific window identifier corresponding to the window’s outermost parent. For Unix, this is the X window identifier. For Windows, this is the HWND cast to a long integer.

There is also additional information about getting the HWND [here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_id-method)

> **winfo_id()** [[#](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_id-method)]
> Get a system-specific window identifier for this widget. For Unix, this is the X window identifier. For Windows, this is the HWND cast to a long integer.
>
> Returns:
>       The window identifier.

I believe using `winfo_id()` above, you should be able to get the HWND of the window.

Comment: Great, I was able to render with [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) to the tkinter window.