# How do I get the HWND of a window made with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to get the HWND of a window made with tkinter?

I have already tried this:

```
print(root.winfo_id())
print(getAllWindows())
```

However, there is no `root.winfo_id()` in the list of `getAllWindows()`
Why so?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's an HWND?

Comment: You can use `pywin32` module in Windows platform: `win32gui.GetParent(root.winfo_id())`.

Comment: Try this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218662/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-a-tkinter-window-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the HWND of a Tkinter window on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218662/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-a-tkinter-window-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
   hwnd = root.winfo_id()
   parent_hwnd = win32gui.GetParent(hwnd)
   text = win32gui.GetWindowText(parent_hwnd)
   print(text)
```

it will return "System menu", which means it is what you want.
Apparently there is a wrapper
This simple window coded in [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.org);

[image: Window coded in pySimpleGUI]

have the following windows (as shown by [Spy++](https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus)) :

[image]

The first window in the list is the one we catch (it as 'System menu' as title bar!)