# How to uniquely get the win32api/win32gui figure handle from the matplotlib figure object

Tags: python, matplotlib, pywin32

I wonder what is the best way to uniquely obtain the `win32gui`'s window handle given the `matplotlib`'s figure object.

I know I can find it based on the window title with `win32gui.FindWindow()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import win32gui

fig = plt.figure()
my_title = 'My Figure'
fig.canvas.manager.window.title(my_title)
hdl = win32gui.FindWindow(None, my_title)
print(hdl)

>>> 7735822 (just an arbitrary number here)
```

but this method fails if I have more than one window with the same title (the reasons why to do so are out of the question), since `FindWindow` seems to return only the first result that matches the search:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()
my_title = 'My Figure'
fig1.canvas.manager.window.title(my_title)
fig2.canvas.manager.window.title(my_title)  # Both figures have same window title
hdl = win32gui.FindWindow(None, my_title)
print(hdl)

>>> 6424880 (just another one arbitrary number here)
```

In the second example at least it would be nice if `hdl` were a list of handles with all matches found.

I seems logical to me that if I have the specific python object pointing to the figure, there must be a unique way to get the `win32gui` window handle, but I can't find the answer anywhere. Something like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
hdl = fig.get_w32_handle()
# or
hdl = win32gui.GetWindowFromID(id(fig))
```

Comment: Could you make the window titles "unique" by merely adding a different number of white spaces to the end of  the titles? For window #1, add 1 space. For window #2, add two spaces. They would look the same to the user, but you could then use the title to tag each uniquely.

Comment: Yes, sure I could do that, even I thought retitling the window temporarily while I do  the operations I want to do and then retitle it back. But again, that's not the true point of my question... what I find hard to believe is that having the unique python object that identifies my window, there is not a simple (e.g. one-liner) way to retrieve it's Windows handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218662/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-a-tkinter-window-on-windows) after searching again by using the 'Tkinter' keyword rather than 'matplotlib'

Basically I can get the Windows handle (in hexadecimal) with the `frame()` method and convert it do decimal to then use it with the win32 api:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import win32gui

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()

my_title = 'My Figure'
fig1.canvas.manager.window.title(my_title)
fig2.canvas.manager.window.title(my_title)  # Both figures have same window title

hdl1 = int(fig1.canvas.manager.window.frame(), 16)  # Hex -> Dec
hdl2 = int(fig2.canvas.manager.window.frame(), 16)  

print(hdl1, ':', win32gui.GetWindowText(hdl1))
print(hdl2, ':', win32gui.GetWindowText(hdl2))


>>> 199924 : My Figure
>>> 396520 : My Figure
```